# Vertically Aligning Up to Three Rows in a Parent Div

Tags: html, center, vertical-alignment, css-tables

**EDIT: I have solved my own problem. I have commented my code below where the error was. I will add an answer as soon as I'm able.**

---

I have a header bar on my page which could have up to three rows of data:

- Page Title
- Page Information
- Page Badges

However, the page-info bar and the page-badges bar are shown dynamically; sometimes they're there (depending on the data coming in), and sometimes they're not.

**Goal:** I want to ensure that everything stays nice and vertically centered in the header area, if one or more of the aforementioned rows is not present because there's nothing to render.

I attempted to use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`, but it doesn't seem to be working out. Here's my code:

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div class="header-bar">
    <div class="header-bar-wrapper">
        <h1 class="page-title">Charity Challenge Golf Outing</h1>
        <div class="page-info">
            <h5 class="item"><span class="info-label">Project</span>US Asset</h5>
            <h5 class="item"><span class="info-label">Project Manager</span>John Smith</h5>
            <h5 class="item"><span class="info-label">Start Date</span>11/22/2013</h5>
            <h5 class="item"><span class="info-label">End Date</span>12/25/2013</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="page-badges">
            <span class="page-badge">
                <span class="page-badge-icon"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i></span>
                <span class="page-badge-value">10</span>
                <span class="page-badge-text">Cups Consumed</span>
            </span>
            <span class="page-badge">
                <span class="page-badge-icon"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i></span>
                <span class="page-badge-value">3</span>
                <span class="page-badge-text">Days Remaining</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.header-bar {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:79px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0 20px;
}

.header-bar-wrapper {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:center; // THIS WAS MY ERROR. Should be vertical-align:middle
}

.page-title,
.page-info,
.page-badges {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    clear:both;
}

.page-title {
    margin:0;
    font-size:29px;
}

.page-info {

}

.page-badges {
    bottom:0;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

**[Here is a Fiddle with the aforementioned code.](http://jsfiddle.net/2qFA8/1/)**

Comment: It looks fine to me even when I removed `page-badges`...

Comment: The title and the page-info should shift down so that they're vertically centered in the header. They don't seem to be doing this.

Comment: Nevermind, it is working. I had to change `vertical-align:center` to `vertical-align:middle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using `vertical-align:center` instead of `vertical-align:middle`. **This fixed my code.**

**[Here's an updated Fiddle with working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/2qFA8/3/)**

Try deleting either the `page-badges` or `page-info` block and you'll see how everything stays centered vertically.